# Can't view XAMPP localhost Page except Apache "It Works!"

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, xampp

I am currently using Windows XP SP3 with Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3, MySQL 5.1 and XAMPP 1.7.3 installed.

However after installing everything including XAMPP, I could not see the "XAMPP Welcome Page" at all! I only see the Apache default Page "It Works!!" on http://localhost/ . I also tried http://127.0.0.1/ but it gives back the same Apache results. My Apache and MySQL service seems to be running fine on the XAMPP console.

I have also placed a php file under C:\program files\apache\htdocs\test.php and access the page via http://localhost/test.php which works fine! I really can't guess why isn't the XAMPP installed over the Apache.

Can anyone please give some advice on the problem? Thanks.

Comment: do you run stand alone apache and XAMPP altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAMPP is a standalone AMP solution, so you don't need to install Apache or anything else with it. And if you do, both servers will probably conflict.

You need to either uninstall XAMPP, or uninstall Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

Note that XAMPP needs to be started up through its control panel, accessible from whatever start menu folder it will have created.

EDIT: Also, XAMPP has its own htdocs folder, located in `C:\xampp\htdocs`

Comment: So all I have to do is to uninstall everything a just reinstall the XAMPP alone? But how does the Apache, PHP and MySQL gets installed? Unless the XAMPP has all the installation files in it already?

Comment: Your solution to the XAMPP works like a charm dude! Thanks! The problem was due to 2 Apache servers colliding with one another. Users should just only install the XAMPP program to fully run the apache properly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can switch the port of the Apache server that came with your XAMPP installation via httpd.conf. and as it is described [here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/) for example:

Just remember to address the corresponding pages via http://localhost:XXXX
XXXX being the new portnummer you picked (for example 8080).

Answer (score 0):

check the port from xampp control panel >config > Apache httpd.conf

then [image]